# Vue Js npm run serve taking so long to build+

Tags: vue.js, npm, networking, nic

I have VueJs frontend and NodeJs backend. The machine(CPU: 11th gen intel, disk: 932GB SSD, RAM: 32GB) which this application is running have 4 Network Interface Cards (eth1,eth2,eth3 and eth4). When I serve vue application by npm run serve while all the interfaces are active, it's taking so much time to build and loading of the webpage is also slow. Anyone know the how to fix this?
Backend application is running without any delay. I have already set there the app.listen() to the particular IP.

It's fast when I disable other network interfaces and only one network card is active , there is no issue.

Comment: Vue is browser UI framework, it doesn't affect the way you build the app. The question is unspecific. If your problem is Vue CLI then ask about it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.